# "Command not found" (simple bash script)

Tags: bash

I need to write a basic program which would find the files which have odd (uneven) size in bytes in user specified directory and then rename them. I wrote a code but can't figure it out what's wrong with it since I have only just began to programm bash scripts... I have 3 files in my directory and here are the errors I'am getting for them:

```
./Untitled: line 18: AppIcon.icns: command not found

mv: cannot stat ‘AppIcon.icns’: No such file or directory
./Untitled: line 18: AssociatedVm.txt: command not found

mv: cannot stat ‘AssociatedVm.txt’: No such file or directory
./Untitled: line 18: Info.plist: command not found

mv: cannot stat ‘Info.plist’: No such file or directory
```

My script Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0

echo “Specify directory” 

read directory

if [ -d $directory ]; then

         echo “Directory found”

else 
    echo “Directory not found” 

exit 0

fi

for file in $( ls $directory );

do

fsize=$(stat "$directory/$file" -c %s)


if [ $((fsize%2))=1 ]; then 


mv "$directory/$file" "$directory/$file.odd"


n=$((n + 1))


fi
 done

echo ”Number of renamed files: $n ”
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls`. Use shell globs. And quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant

```
fsize=$(stat "$file" -c %s)
```

but you wrote

```
fsize=stat "$file" -c %s
```

Also, you need to use the absolute path(`$directory/$file`) instead of `$file` alone if you are running the script from a directory which is not `$directory`.

Bash uses `-eq` for integer comparison, so you should also change

```
if [ $((fsize%2))=1 ]; then
```

to

```
if [ $((fsize%2)) -eq 1 ]; then
```

What is the `-c %s` for? I don't see a `-c` option in the `stat` man page. Did you mean `-f`? (**EDIT**: Ok I was looking at the Mac `stat` command (which is BSD). The `stat` in [GNU version](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html) uses `-c` for format specification)

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the errors (I updated the code). HOVEWER, for some reason now it renames all of the files in directory. How could I make it rename only the ones with uneven(odd) size? I confused myself right now lol. –

Comment: Ah, bash uses `-eq` for integer comparison, so you should change `$((fsize%2))=1` to `$((fsize%2)) -eq 1` (updated the answer as well).